# NSXML parser with UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have an XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<user id="1" name=""><class id="1" name=""><subjects id="1" name=""><books id="1" name="">   
<chapters id="1" name="">
<pages id="0" name="" url="http://172.11.133.12/uploads/mathematic/Page001.html"/>
<pages id="1" name="" url="http://172.11.133.12/uploads/mathematic/Page002.html"/>
</chapters>
<chapters id="2" name="">
<pages id="0" name="" url="http://172.11.133.12/uploads/mathematic1/Page001.html"/>
<pages id="1" name="" url="http://172.11.133.12/uploads/mathematic1/Page002.html"/>
</chapters>
</books></subjects></class></user>
```

Here i have parsed this using NSXML Parser, and everything works fine, here i need to display the Chapters Id in UItableview and when user selects any chapter the URL should be opened in Webview. I have displayed all chapter names in TableView cell, i want to know how can i get the corresponding URL values for each Chapter Tag.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

currentElement = [elementName copy];

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"chapters"]) {
    flag = 0;
    chapID = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"id"];


}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pages"]){

    urlValue = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
}
```

Here i need to store the corresponding Pages tag inside the Chapter... please guide me..

Comment: You need to explain how your parsed data is stored. Do you have an array of dictionaries? You already have logic in your `cellForRow...` method to get the chapter name for each row. It should be the same logic to get the chapter id or URL for a row in your `didSelectRow...` method.

Comment: I'm using mutable array which holds chapId. Where in cellForRow i'm doing like this cell.textLabel.text = [idchap objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: And how are the URLs stored? Is it another array that is the same size as the chapter id array?

Comment: THANKS maddy...I done that, but only first page is loading in didSelectRow, i want to show all pages when user swipes. I'm loading it in webview...